# Why DIA SDK get_guid always returns Bad ptr(0x000) for Class guid?

Tags: visual-c++, com, pdb-files, dbghelp, dia-sdk

I am using DIA SDK for enumerating types and interfaces of COM binaries(dlls/exes).
But get_guid always returns Bad  Ptr(0x0000) for every Class(CoClass & Interface) used inside that component?

Any way out other by which we can get guid from pdb of co class and interface.

Regards
Usman

Comment: Roll in the code - what you call, how you call it and what exactly returns that error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're creating the COM appartment using CoInitialize(NULL)?